# Django 1.7.7 annotate creating field. Cannot resolve keyword into field

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, aggregate, m2m

FieldError at /admin/stocks/present/8/
Cannot resolve keyword 'null_count' into field.

```
        class TireManager(models.Manager):
            def get_queryset(self):
                qs = super(TireManager, self).get_queryset()
                return qs.annotate(null_count=models.Count('present_tire__id')).order_by('-null_count', 'price')


        class Tire(models.Model):

            name = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Наименование', max_length=200, default='')
            objects = TireManager()

        class Present(models.Model):
            tire = models.ManyToManyField(Tire, verbose_name=u'Шины',null=True, blank=True, related_name='present_tire')
```

I update django from 1.4.5 to 1.7.7 and when I open the admin edit page model Present, an error is displayed. This code working in 1.4.5 and i don't know what wrong becouse this error only in admin change model Present, on other pages with qs annotated manager this works.

```
Traceback:
File "/home/konstantin.gabbasov/redsolution_projects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/konstantin.gabbasov/redsolution_projects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  583.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  206.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1456.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  394.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1419.                 form = ModelForm(instance=obj)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  319.             object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in model_to_dict
  149.                     data[f.name] = list(qs.values_list('pk', flat=True))
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  141.         self._fetch_all()
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  966.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  1202.             for row in self.query.get_compiler(self.db).results_iter():
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  700.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  775.             sql, params = self.as_sql()
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  101.         ordering, o_params, ordering_group_by = self.get_ordering()
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in get_ordering
  429.                         self.query.get_meta(), default_order=asc):
File "/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in find_ordering_name
  465.         field, targets, alias, joins, path, opts = self._setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in _setup_joins
  498.             pieces, opts, alias)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in setup_joins
  1463.             names, opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True)
File "/home/konstsov/redsolutjects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in names_to_path
  1427.             self.raise_field_error(opts, name)
File "/home/konstantin.gabbasov/redsolution_projects/oko/venvi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in raise_field_error
  1433.                          "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /admin/stocks/present/8/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'null_count' into field. Choices are: article, balance, brand, brand_id, diameter, discount_tire, fixed_item, height, id, info_tire, last_modified, long_title, name, present_tire, price, season, show, slug, studs, tabs, width
```

Comment: This example also get error.

Comment: Please post the complete models.